# How can we give an example of a function f such that all the directional derivatives of f at the origin are ±1.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

How can we give an example of a function f such that all the directional derivatives of f at the origin are ±1?

This is a question intrigues me for a while. My idea is to use the formula: when directional derivatives exist, it equals gradient vector at **0** times (cosθ,sinθ). I tried a few examples, and don't know where I'm heading to.

Can someone share some lights on this issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How about $f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta) = \pm r$ with a `+` sign when $\theta \in (0,\pi]$ and `-` when $\theta \in (-\pi,0]$. You essentially take a cone, cut it into two, flip one of them upside down to make the directional derivatives defined at origin

Comment: I think you probably solved the question, thank you hui!